# React Native access variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to access to different variables with indexing.

first I created them:

```
  const refRBSheet0 = useRef();
  const refRBSheet1 = useRef();
  const refRBSheet2 = useRef();
  const refRBSheet3 = useRef();
  const refRBSheet4 = useRef();
```

and now I want to access them with something like:

```
onPress={() => [refRBSheet + index].current.open()}
```

or

```
onPress={() => {refRBSheet + index.toString}.current.open()}
```

but none of them works for me.

Comment: You just created `refs` but then they haven't been assigned/mapped to any DOM elements.

Comment: @NithishGandesiri thanks, but thats not the problem. I just want to know how to access them with index..

Comment: Instead of creating different ref's, you can just create array of refs and can access using the index from that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create arrays of refs and use based on index.

```
const refRBSheet = [useRef(),useRef(),useRef(),useRef(),useRef()]

onPress={() => refRBSheet[index].current.open()}
```